# Question about configuring SSL for CAMEL LDAP

Tags: apache-camel

Currently I am reading the document http://camel.apache.org/ldap.html

and try to configure SSL for LDAP , I did not find how or where the bean 
ldapserver refers to the bean customSocketFactory. 
Any suggestions or hints are more than welcome!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

```
<sslContextParameters xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
                      id="sslContextParameters">
    <keyManagers
            keyPassword="{{keystore.pwd}}">
        <keyStore
                resource="{{keystore.url}}"
                password="{{keystore.pwd}}"/>
    </keyManagers>
</sslContextParameters>

<bean id="customSocketFactory" class="zotix.co.util.CustomSocketFactory">
    <argument ref="sslContextParameters" />
</bean>
<bean id="ldapserver" class="javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext" scope="prototype">
    <argument>
        <props>
            <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/>
            <prop key="java.naming.provider.url" value="ldaps://lab.zotix.co:636"/>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.protocol" value="ssl"/>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.authentication" value="simple" />
            <prop key="java.naming.security.principal" value="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com"/>
            <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials" value="passw0rd"/>
            <prop key="java.naming.ldap.factory.socket"
                  value="zotix.co.util.CustomSocketFactory"/>
        </props>
    </argument>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is this line from the config you posted that creates the link

```
<prop key="java.naming.ldap.factory.socket" value="zotix.co.util.CustomSocketFactory"/>
```

I guess that normally an instance of `zotix.co.util.CustomSocketFactory` is created. But *because there is already one* in the Spring context it uses that one. Therefore *no explicit link between the two beans is needed*.

I am only guessing, but you can test that by (de-)activating the `customSocketFactory` bean. If this switches between a standard (non-SSL) and the SSL factory, it seems to be like this.